# Docker-compose communication between containers refused

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two Docker containers managed by a Docker Compose configuration, and I need to establish communication between them, specifically sending data from one container to the other.

This is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  logic:
    build:
      context: ./logic
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
  action:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: 
      - .env
    ports:
      - 7071:7071
```

And this is the logic container Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

According to the docker-compose [networking documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), I understand that in order to send data from the action container to the logic, I need to use the  `http://logic:5000` URL. However, I get a connection refused error.

`root@99e671f7e3d9:/app# curl -X POST -d "key1=value1&key2=value2" http://logic:5000`

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to logic port 5000: Connection refused`

Also, it seems that indeed the logic container listens to 5000 port for incoming calls

```
root@93edd7abe469:/app# netstat -tuln | grep 5000 

tcp        0      0
127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

What could be the issue? I have also tried to reach to the logic container using it's IP but didn't work either.

Comment: Seems like you have done it correctly, are you sure that the logic service is running in the port 5000?

Comment: Have you tried to reach the 'logic' container from the host, or even from within the container itself? just to verify the port is open....

Comment: Please post the logic docker file in order to check it.

Comment: `ports:` maps container ports to the host, so whatever you have in the logic container running on port 5000 is also accessible from your host at `http://localhost:5000` - does that work?  Are you sure you have something running on port 5000 in that container?

Comment: The other important thing to check is that the thing running in the `logic` container is listening on the 0.0.0.0 "all interfaces" address; if it's only listening on 127.0.0.1, that's a container-private localhost address, and the process will be unreachable from outside its own container.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], especially showing what the main container process is and how it sets up its network listener?

Comment: Indeed @DavidMaze the Python app was not listening to the all interfaces address. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The container waiting for incoming connections was binding to 127.0.0.1 instead of binding to all the available network addresses. This is why I couldn't access it from another container using the http://logic:5000.

The solution was to bind to all network interfaces by updating the Python Flask code as below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```